# Get a error message after installing modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, path

I installed a couple of modules and after installation, the following message came.

```
WARNING: The script pygmentize.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\ebben\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts iptest.exe, iptest3.exe, ipython.exe and ipython3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\ebben\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts jupyter-migrate.exe, jupyter-troubleshoot.exe and jupyter.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\ebben\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script jsonschema.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\ebben\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script jupyter-trust.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\ebben\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts jupyter-kernel.exe, jupyter-kernelspec.exe and jupyter-run.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\ebben\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts jupyter-bundlerextension.exe, jupyter-nbextension.exe, jupyter-notebook.exe and jupyter-serverextension.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\ebben\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script jupyter-console.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\ebben\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script isympy.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\ebben\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  WARNING: The scripts nosetests-3.4.exe and nosetests.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\ebben\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

I don't know much about modules and have no idea how to fix this without messing something up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add `C:\Users\ebben\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts` to PATH in order to be able to run the modules from the command line. Assuming you're on Windows 10, follow [these instructions](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/).